# SQL generate column name with number in pivot

Tags: sql

I don't exactly know how to articulate this question, so apology if this has been asked before. Here I have this query to pivot a table:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT
         [cashValue],
         [Name], 
         [t] 
     FROM
         [DBName].[dbo].[TableName]) AS SourceTable
     PIVOT 
         (MAX([cashValue])
              FOR [t] IN ([1],[2],[3])
         ) AS PivotTable
```

Notice I have the "[1],[2],[3]" when I need to generate the column name? My [t] has value spanning from 1 to 51. Can I just write a loop to generate [1] all the way to [51] ?

Thanks

Comment: You can easily do this in a spreadsheeet.

Comment: that's a rather smart solution. So SQL doesn't have something like (d)=> while d<51, d++ ?

Comment: . . In many databases, you can construct a query to return a string with the values.  However, SQL does not support dynamic references to columns.